# eventStoreChenged error and app crashes

Tags: ios

I keep getting eventStoreChanged error and app crashes. I have implemented Kal calendar in my app.I am creating custom calendar and adding events to it some times apps crashes while adding events other times its crashing while creating calendar please any body help me on this

Comment: Any code? Error message?

Comment: [__NSCFDictionary eventStoreChanged:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15fdea40

2015-02-21 13:52:17.414 DCSmart[1222:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary eventStoreChanged:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15fdea40'

Answer (score 0):

Set  eventStoreChanged.delegate to nil
then your issue must be solved

Comment: where I  have to set this any code example will be very helpful

Comment: Hi Vishnu to do this delegate methods should be there right